# Vagrant Install Errors

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, berkshelf

I am trying to install a new version of Vagrant with a LAMP stack and Chef on Mac OSX.  I have chef-dk, vagrant, and virtual box installed. I have installed the precise32 box (vagrant box add precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box) and berkshelf (gem install berkshelf as well as: vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf).  I have tried deleting everything and re-installing, but I keep getting this error:

```
# vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
/private/var/root/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-3.0.1/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/config.rb:70:in `expand_path': can't convert Berkshelf::Vagrant::ChefConfig::Proxy to String (Berkshelf::Vagrant::ChefConfig::Proxy#to_str gives Berkshelf::Vagrant::ChefConfig::Proxy) (TypeError)
        from /private/var/root/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-3.0.1/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/config.rb:70:in `validate'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/root.rb:68:in `block in validate'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/root.rb:64:in `each'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/config/v2/root.rb:64:in `validate'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:15:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /private/var/root/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-3.0.1/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action/configure_chef.rb:13:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /private/var/root/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-3.0.1/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/action/load_shelf.rb:13:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:196:in `action_raw'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:173:in `block in action'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:434:in `lock'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `call'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `action'
        from /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Any thoughts here?

Comment: I've had my share of my problems with this setup, though my error messages were different. There could be conflicts within your PATH - Berkshelf, for example, is bundled in the Chef-DK, yet you also have it installed as a gem. What does your PATH look like?

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix it by deleting chefdk and bershelf, then just re-installing chefdk.  It was the conflict of the gem install and the one included in chef causing the error.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

We've already discussed the answer in the comments, and I'm glad it was just a PATH issue. I haven't seen your particular error message anywhere else on this site, so it might be useful to leave it up for others.

For anyone else arriving here, the problem is due to conflicts between ChefDK and any other versions of Ruby and Berkshelf you might have installed. So make sure:

There are no other versions of Berkshelf installed.

You have `vagrant-berkshelf` installed as a vagrant plugin

These two lines are near/at the bottom of your .bash_profile, so that ChefDK is encountered at the start of your PATH:

```
export PATH=/opt/chefdk/bin:$PATH
eval "$(chef shell-init bash)"
```

There are no conflicts with RVM, chruby, or other ruby installations. If you have any lines like the following in your .bash_profile, try commenting them out:

```
# Comment out chruby
# source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
# source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
# chruby ruby-1.9
```

Running `which berks`, or `which ruby`, should produce a response that begins `/opt/chefdk/`